# targeting PLupload div in CSS to overwrite the inline styles

Tags: html, css, plupload

What would be the best way to target the following `div`? It contains inline styles that I need to override but that jumbled group of numbers is not possible to target since each button has it's own. I tried `IDing` it in the style sheet, but still no dice. I tried doing `div.moxie-shim.moxie-shim-html5` with !important tags and all, and even target it through the ID of the form. Thanks

```
<div id="html5_1bv5o0e5e18dsj3dhdm125oml1h_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5" style="position: absolute; top: 48px; left: 16px; width: 81px; height: 28px; overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
[class="moxie-shim"] {
    style: myStyle;
}
```

Seems like you're not targeting with the correct syntax.